# Test Accounts for in-app purchase for Amazon android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am an Android developer.

I implemented IAP(in-app-purchase) for Amazon perfectly.

I would like to do real-purchase with test accounts with [Amazon App Store](https://developer.amazon.com/home.html) as we already did in [Google Play Store](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-testing-setup)

Is there any possibility of adding Test-Accounts in Amazon App Store?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

I dont know whether it is available for Production release, but there is facility adding testers while releasing ***Live App Testing***

The email id which i have added in testers list, I did sign up in [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin?_encoding=UTF8&openid.assoc_handle=usflex&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.pape=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fpape%2F1.0&openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fgp%2Fyourstore%2Fhome%3Fie%3DUTF8%26ref_%3Dnav_custrec_signin)

I added credit card details to 1-click settings and I purchased from My-APP. Amount is not deducted from my credit card